# A question about the norm of an element in a field extension.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

**Background:** Since $x^3\not\equiv2\pmod{7}, \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can let $K=\mathbb{F_7}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ so that $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F_7}$, which can be think of as a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F_7}$ with a basis $(1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4})$. Then the norm of an element $\alpha=x+y\sqrt[3]{2}+z\sqrt[3]{4}$ is defined to be $N(\alpha)=x^3+2y^3+4y^3-6xyz$, which is the determinant of the linear transformation $f_\alpha:K \rightarrow K$ defined as left multiplication by $\alpha$ in $K$.

**My question** is that if I have an element $\beta\in K$ having a unit norm, i.e. $N(\beta)=1$, can I then conclude that $N(\beta\alpha)=N(\beta)N(\alpha)=N(\alpha)$? I.e., is $N$ a homomorphism?

**My attempt** Observe that $f_{\beta\alpha}=f_\beta\circ f_\alpha$, then $$N(\beta\alpha)=\det(f_{\beta\alpha})=\det(f_\beta)\det(f_\alpha)=N(\beta)N(\alpha).$$

**My motivation:** Then $x^3+2y^3+4z^3-6xyz=2$ has infinitely many integral solutions since we can just find an $\alpha$ s.t. $N(\alpha)=2$ and some non-identity $\beta$ s.t. $N(\beta)=1 \Rightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, N(\beta^n\alpha)=2$, i.e. we have infinitely many solutions to the give cubic form.

Comment: I cannot poke any holes in your reasoning.  This seems to yield an infinite family of solutions, if indeed the real numbers $ \beta^n \alpha $ are unique.  If it's an important problem to you, I recommend you try crunching out two or three examples to see that the results are correct and non-trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $N$ is a homomorphism. One easy way to see this is that determinants are multiplicative.

I.e., if $L/K$ is a field extension, and $\alpha,\beta \in L$, and if $\theta\in L$, then $\mu_\theta : L\to L$ denotes the map $\mu_\theta(x) = \theta\cdot x$, then we have 
$$N(\alpha \beta) = \det \mu_{\alpha\beta} = \det (\mu_\alpha \circ \mu_\beta) = \det \mu_\alpha \cdot \det \mu_\beta = N(\alpha)N(\beta).$$

**Edit**

You just added your attempt, and it's what I have here. So good work!

Comment: Thank you! Could you also help me check whether the problem in "my motivation" is solved by just observing that $N$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: @MΣW3 Yes, it does solve your problem. Assuming you can actually find $\alpha$, and some $\beta\ne 1$. (Note you say $\beta \ne 0$, but you need $\beta \ne 1$). Also if you want infinitely many integral solutions you need to work in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ rather than in the finite field. That said, we have $(0,1,0)$ has norm 2 and $(1,1,1)$ has norm 1, so it works.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful remarks!